# Anyone know how to do multiplayer in a java rts game?

Tags: java, multiplayer

Recently I started making my own multiplayer rts game with java and need help with the multiplayer part. I would like it to have a server list where people host from their own computer and it shows up on the main list if they say it's ok. For the game I have a working game where if in the code you change a Boolean to false you will play the blue team and if it's true you will be red. I hope to make it so you can choose your own team color and, depending on the host's preference, there can be more than 2 people playing at once. I would need all players to see the others moving characters and the characters will need to be able to attack each other. I believe, correct me if I'm wrong, I'll need to do this using packets.

Even if you yourself can't help but you know a good reference that could I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest checking this out http://code.google.com/p/lucu/

> Here you will find information about how to create your own video
>   game. I hope you enjoy this guide. Happy gaming!
>
> The files hosted here are:
>
> A java 2D multiplayer game (with source) A java 3D multiplayer game
>   (with source) Tutorial on how those games were created